# Calculate time between 9:00 AM -- 6:00 PM

Tags: c#

I'm having a string with 8:00 AM. Suppose I want to check that time 8:00 AM comes before 9:00 Am -- 6:00 PM.
How to check this or if time 11:00 AM comes in between time 9:00 AM -- 6:00 PM?
How to find it out in c#?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the DateTime object, its static parse method, and comparison operators.
Something like the following:

```
newTime = DateTime.Parse("8:00 AM");
fixedTime = DateTime.Parse("11:00 AM");
if (newTime < fixedTime)
{
// do something
}
```

If needed, you can subtract one DateTime from another to get a TimeSpan - that is a duration.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "8:00 AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(s);

if (dt < DateTime.Parse("9:00 AM"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before");
}
else if (dt <= DateTime.Parse("6:00 PM"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Between");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("After");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The general method would be to convert the time to a number that you can then use to compare.

So 8:00 AM would be simply 8, 6:00 PM would be 18, therefore 18 > 8 etc.

Answer (score 0):

The function DateTime.Parse() can be used to turn strings into "DateTime" objects.

You have your start time:  9:00AM.

You have your end time:  6:00PM.

You therefore have your distance between the two:

6:00PM - 9:00AM.

That will give you a TimeSpan object.

Then you take your 'mystery time', and do:

X:XX - 9:00AM.

If the resulting timespan is > 0 AND the resulting timespan is < 6:00PM-9:00AM tiemspan, you're good.

Alternately, you can simply do

if (myTime > 9:00AM && myTime < 6:00PM)

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime beginDate = DateTime.Today.AddHours(9);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today.AddHours(18);

TimeSpan diff = endDate - beginDate;
```

Now `diff` contains difference between begin date and end date.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
int _dateTimeCompare = DateTime.Compare(DateTime1, DateTime2);
```

and then _dateTimeCompare < 1 = DateTime 1 is less than DateTime2, 0 = they're the same, > 0 = DateTime2 > DateTime1

So you can then do the comparisons.

A simple is _myDate between _date1 and _date2 would then be:

```
if (DateTime.Compare(_myDate, _date1) >= 0 && DateTime.Compare(_myDate, _date2) <= 0)
{
    // we're between _date1 and _date2
}
```

kinda thing :)

Comment: I'd add, you don't mention whether the actual date is significant or not - 8am today is actually > 10am yesterday (well, of course!), so you need to be careful with your DateTime.Compare to make sure your data is representative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem casting the strings to DateTime variables (as they should be) and then using the `Compare` method to perform the comparison.

Additionally, the DateTime structure implements operators such as `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=` which simplify comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse your string into a TimeSpan object using TimeSpan.Parse or TimeSpan.TeyParse.

If the parse succeeds, you'll have a TimeSpan object that can be compared to other timespan objects using the standard comparison operators. You can also carry out operations such as addition and substraction to calculate time between two timespans or to calculate a new time based on a time and duration.

Timespan is a very nice little class, please do not reinvent the wheel.

Update

As remarked by Cerebrus in the comment, TimeSpan is kind of weird in the sense that it can represent both a point in time and a duration. (The DateTime.TimeOfDay property is a Timespan even though it is a point in time).
**It is perhaps a better idea to create DateTime objects with a default date part and use this as the basis of calculations. The intent of the code will be clearer.**
Operations such as comparisons, additions and substractions are also available on DateTimes and yield DateTimes or TimeSpan where applicable.

Comment: You may be slightly off the mark as per the intent of the question. TimeSpan represents a duration in time, not an instant in time as the DateTime class does.

Comment: Well, it's debatable. I know it does represent a duration, but apparently the framework team also intended it to represent a point in time, as exposed by the Date.Time property which returns a TimeSpan. 
I happen to disagree with this choice, but it is what it is. It leads to weird behaviors if you are not careful, but it can work.
It is true I also use a DateTime with the default date part, so I'll update my answer to reflect that.
Thanks for the remark.

Comment: Now that I read the documentation more closely I understand my mistake. TimeOfDay represents the time elapsed since midnight on the date represented by the DateTime, so in effect it is not a point in time but a duration. Still, as a "vector" type, assuming a midnight "origin" it should work, but it certainly is not clear in its intent if used that way.
Apologies for submitting a bad idea, practice-wise.